# How to get a command to start on startup

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have to run  [`bluetoothctl`](http://manpages.org/bluetoothctl) to get my bluetooth dongle to work every time I start the pi.
Is there a way to get the command to run on start up?
I am running kali 2.0.1 on my [pi2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/).

Answer (score 1):

You can place the invocation of the script in `/etc/rc.local`.

This file will be run on startup, so  place the command you want to run at the end of the file, and it will be invoked on startup.

Another way is creating a LSB init script and place it under `/etc/init.d`. These scripts have to follow [some rules](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/) to be considered LSB compliant. After adding it to this directory, you simply enable it with `update-rc.d yourscript defaults`.

Comment: can  you give more detailed instuction how to do this via this method /etc/rc.local

Comment: So easily, simply open up `/etc/rc.local` and put the whole command at the end of the file: `bluetoothctl ...`. Save the file and reboot to test.